# PIVOT após a execução a mensagem fica como "Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'FOR'."

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Preciso que meus dados retornem as informações dos clientes por cursos em uma única linha, ou seja, os vários cursos distintos realizados ao invés de virem em linhas individuais precisam aparecer em novas colunas na linha respectiva ao cliente.

Utilizei o comando **PIVOT Table** para ordenar conforme necessito, mas ao executar surge a mensagem:

> Sintaxe incorreta próxima à palavra-chave 'FOR'.

Vou sintetizar meu código:

```
SELECT [CLIENTE],
      [CURSO 1],
      [CURSO 2],
      [CURSO 3],
      [CURSO 4],
      [CURSO 5],
      [CURSO 6],
      [CURSO 7]
 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      [CLIENTE],
      [CURSO],
      [CH CURSO CT]
   .
   .
   ) AS CLIENTE

    PIVOT ([CH CURSO CT] FOR [CURSO] IN
         ([CURSO 1],
         [CURSO 2],
         [CURSO 3],
         [CURSO 4],
         [CURSO 5],
         [CURSO 6],
         [CURSO 7]))
    AS PVT
```

Quem puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 0):

Roberto, antes do FOR deve-se informar uma função de agregação. Algo como max(), avg(), sum() etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso do seu código talvez você possa utilizar

```
       PIVOT (max ([CH CURSO CT]) FOR [CURSO] IN
```

Detalhes no artigo “[Alas & Pivôs](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/05/04/pivot/)”.